# How do you specify a local database instance in TSQL with the USE keyword?

Tags: t-sql

I have several database names which exist on local, dev and live servers.
I want to ensure a potentially dangerous T-SQL script will always use the local db and not any other db by accident.

I can't seem to use the [USE] keyword with the local instance name followed by the db name.
It seems pretty trivial but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried this but no luck:

```
USE [MYMACHINE/SQLEXPRESS].[DBNAME]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance is going to be determined through your connection/connection string.  You connect to a specific instance and then all subsequent T-SQL will be executed against that instance and that instance alone.

Comment: Once the database used by the connection is selected, you cannot change it.

Comment: Is there any other way in which I can prevent scripts from being accidentally ran then on the wrong instance?

Comment: @jaffa Yes of course there is a way to prevent your scripts form being accidentally ran on the wrong instance of LocalDB file. I created and answer for this, sorry for it being so late however thought it could be helpful to other users searching for this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is not correct for the question asked. As you can specify a specific LocalDB file via the USE command in T-SQL. You just have to specify the fully qualified path name, which is what you will also see in the dropdown for the database list.

```
USE [C:\MyPath\MyData.mdf]
GO
```